# Backbone appends to list view instead of replacing it

Tags: backbone.js

I am producing a single page website with Wordpress and Backbone.js, i have come into a problem with when i fetch new data. It simply adds DOM elements onto the container el rather than replacing them. The collection updates correctly as i can see it has the right amount of elements in the console.

```
var PostItem = Backbone.Model.extend();

var PostItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PostItem,
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
});

var postItems = new PostItems();

var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({ /* Model View */
  tagName : 'article',
  className : 'widget',
  template : _.template( $('#widgetPost').html() ),
  render: function(){
    var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
    this.$el.html( this.template( attributes ) ); 
    return this;
  }
});

var PostListView = Backbone.View.extend({ /* Collection View */
  el : '#content',
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
    this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
  },
  addOne: function(postItem){
    var postView = new PostView({ model : postItem });
    this.$el.append( postView.render().el );
  },
  addAll: function(){
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
  },
  render: function(){
    this.addAll();
  },
});

var postListView = new PostListView({
  collection : postItems
});

$(function(){

  $('a#posts').click(function(){
    postItems.fetch({
      data: { 
        action: 'do_ajax', 
        fn: 'get_the_posts'
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('a#pages').click(function(){
    postItems.fetch({
      data: { 
        action: 'do_ajax', 
        fn: 'get_the_pages'
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear out your collectionView's $el! :)

```
addAll: function(){
    this.$el.empty();
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i've noticed that it never seems to call the addAll function for some reason?! So although this solution will probably fix it, it doesn't at present

Comment: As of Backbone 1.0, fetch no longer automatically triggers the 'reset' event. You should bind to 'sync' instead, or pass `{ reset: true }` to the fetch call.